# GUI cannot click when Display video in MFC picture using opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, mfc

I am developing a GUI using MFC that allows to display video using opencv. The GUI allows to automatically resize the control in GUI. It works for video displaying. However, I have problem when video is opening. When video is openning, I cannot click any control or minimize button in that GUI. I also cannot click or move that GUI in the sceen. If I want to close the GUI, I must `Shift+ F5` in visual studio. What is happen with my code. That problem is shown in [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XonRLKImHG8&feature=youtu.be) I would like to show my code as following. Thanks

```
void CDialogResizeDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
        cv::VideoCapture cap(0);
    //VideoCapture cap("C:/Users/lsf-admin/Pictures/Camera Roll/video000.mp4");
    cv::vector<cv::Rect> faces;
    cv::Mat frame;
    cv::Mat graySacleFrame;
    cv::Mat original;
    if (!cap.isOpened())
    {

        return exit(1);
    }

    while (true)
    {
        cap >> frame;
        if (!frame.empty()){

        //clone from original frame
        original = frame.clone();
        }
        CDC* vDC;
        vDC = GetDlgItem(IDC_VIDEO)->GetDC();
        CRect rect;
        GetDlgItem(IDC_VIDEO)->GetClientRect(&rect);
        IplImage* image2=cvCloneImage(&(IplImage)original);
        DisplayIplImageToPictureBox(image2, vDC, rect); //img is IplImage* variable.
        ReleaseDC(vDC);
        if (cv::waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
    }
}
```

You can download my source code at [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s5cz7j91reag4n7/DialogResizeVS2010.rar?dl=0) (visual 2012+ opencv 2.4.10)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to open video in the main application thread. That's why your Window message processing (`WindowProc()`) is blocked and GUI is not responding. You should open your video in separate thread. You can use `AfxBeginThread()` to do that. So it does not block the main application thread. Also please don't call `exit(1);` If you'd like to close the GUI application you should send `WM_QUIT` message by calling:

```
::PostQuitMessage(0);
```

In your case I would simply display error message and return:

```
if (!cap.isOpened())
{
  AfxMessageBox(_T("Failed to load video file"));
  return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. However, I have no expert in AfxBeginThread. Could you edit my application and upload the full answer. It is better to understand for me.

Comment: I have to say that your code needs major refactor. Its better if you do it yourself for educational reasons. We can help you here at stackoverflow to choose the right direction. Read MSDN on AfxBeginThread() to move forward.

Comment: Thank. I resolved it. I would like to add my implementation. I hope it can help someone

Comment: However, I only run it within 1 minute. After that, it show memory problem. Have parameters need free?

Comment: You need to do proper exception handling for OpenCV stuff. Use try/catch around OpenCV calls. Please refer to OpenCV documentation for more details.

Comment: I found it. Let see my answer and thread function. Do you have any comment for that?

Comment: Could you please mark my post as an answer to your original question with GUI lockup problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Thank Andrew Komiagin for suggestion a way to resolve it. Let see my implementation. I hope it can help someone

First, you must add the theread defined in Dlg header

```
public:
static UINT StartThread (LPVOID param);

//structure for passing to the controlling function
typedef struct THREADSTRUCT
{
    CDialogResizeDlg*    _this;
        //you can add here other parameters you might be interested on
} THREADSTRUCT;
```

Second, you write video display in thread function as

```
UINT CDialogResizeDlg::StartThread (LPVOID param)
{

THREADSTRUCT*    ts = (THREADSTRUCT*)param;

//here is the time-consuming process 
//which interacts with your dialog
AfxMessageBox ("Thread is started!");
// TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
cv::VideoCapture cap(0);
//VideoCapture cap("C:/Users/lsf-admin/Pictures/Camera Roll/video000.mp4");
cv::vector<cv::Rect> faces;
cv::Mat frame;
cv::Mat graySacleFrame;
cv::Mat original;
if (!cap.isOpened())
{

    AfxMessageBox(_T("Failed to load video file"));
    //return;
    //return exit(1);
}

while (true)
{
    cap >> frame;
    if (!frame.empty()){

    //clone from original frame
    original = frame.clone();
    }
    CDC* vDC;
    vDC =ts->_this->GetDlgItem(IDC_VIDEO)->GetDC();
    CRect rect;
    ts->_this->GetDlgItem(IDC_VIDEO)->GetClientRect(&rect);
    IplImage* image2=cvCloneImage(&(IplImage)original);
    ts->_this->DisplayIplImageToPictureBox(image2, vDC, rect); //img is IplImage* variable.
    ts->_this->ReleaseDC(vDC);
    if (cv::waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
}

//you can also call AfxEndThread() here
return 1;
```

}

Finnaly, you call the above function in onClick even

```
void CDialogResizeDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    THREADSTRUCT *_param = new THREADSTRUCT;
    _param->_this = this;
    AfxBeginThread (StartThread, _param);
}
```

It works now. However, it only works within 1 minutes. After that, it has error memory problem as following 
It is `image2` did not free. You can call `cvReleaseImage(&image2);` to free it.

Answer (score 0):

For a small purpose and fast result without use thread :you can add this function in mfc project .

```
bool peek_and_pump(void)
{
    MSG msg;

#if defined(_AFX) || defined(_AFXDLL)
    while(::PeekMessage(&msg,NULL,0,0,PM_NOREMOVE))
    {
        if(!AfxGetApp()->PumpMessage())
        {
            ::PostQuitMessage(0);
            return false;
        }
    }
    long lIdle = 0;
    while(AfxGetApp()->OnIdle(lIdle++))
        ;
#else
    if(::PeekMessage(&msg,NULL,0,0,PM_REMOVE))
    {
        ::TranslateMessage(&msg);
        ::DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
#endif

    return true;
}
```

and for example call this function in while(true){}.

attention : with this solution you will have a stop loop in mouse click.

but it's worth a shot.